# Galaxy S2 not switching on after being dropped

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, power-on

My Galaxy S2 dropped today and will not switch on. I dropped it on a very soft surface when this occurred. It usually happens and I just press the on button continuously and this usually does the trick. This is not helping and at the moment if I try to connect it to the charger an empty battery signal is flashing on the screen continuously. Any ideas on what course of action I should take? Could it possibly be a dead battery?

Answer (score 2):

Problems after dropping the phones typically come from two reasons:

1. Physical damage
2. Brown out (unclean voltage drop)

The voltage drop may temporarily lock up the circuit, so you could take out the battery for some time to let it properly reset. Else inspect the connector springs if they're bent and measure the battery voltage, try a spare battery, etc.

Comment: thank you sooooo much :) my connectors just needed cleaning great help